# MySQL - is it safe to check the 6 first characters of a query to be sure it is a SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A coworker of mine has written something really awful.
Our boss wanted to be able to write any SELECT queries from the Back Office of our website, then get the result in CSV format.

Those queries will be executed by our PRODUCTION MySQL cluster.
This back-office *feature* should reject any non-SELECT queries.

So he comes up with a really naive solution for that.
This is the PHP code:

```
function checkQuery()
{
        $sQuery = trim($_POST['query']);
        if (empty($sQuery))
                return false;
        $sCmd = substr($sQuery, 0, 6);
        if (strtolower($sCmd) != 'select')
                return errorDiv('Only SELECT queries are authorized');
        return $sQuery;
}
```

For people not knowing PHP, this code removes white space from the begining and the end of an SQL query string, then get the 6 first characters, transforms them to lowercase characters, and if it doesn't match (erf... loosely match) 'select', the query is rejected.

It looks awful and disgusting to me.
I tried to convince him to create at least another MySQL user, with limited privileges, but he is too lazy to do that.

However I cannot prove him that some kind of hacks are possible.

He uses mysql_query() to run the query string, and this driver rejects multiple queries at once.
I can't find any real exploit, but I think there are at least 50% of chance that something bad can happen.

Maybe some NUL char, or some obscur utf-8 chars can do the trick?

Comment: I would assume that "select * from sys.object; drop table XXXX" would be able to do some damage

Comment: This is what MySQL client applications are for. If he needs it on the web, use phpmyadmin.

Comment: @GunnarKnudsen: `mysql_query()` can only execute one query at maximum.

Comment: Do not use mysql_query. It's deprecated and unsafe. See the tragic tale of Bobby Tables (http://xkcd.com/327/), and then read up on prepared statements with PDO (or mysqli_)

Comment: "I tried to convince him to create at least another MySQL user, with limited privileges, but he is too lazy to do that." I would consider resigning, and taking a job in a more competent, professional environment. To my mind, that's the only way to solve the fundamental technical issue here.

Comment: Can you appeal to a technical manager to get the new MySQL user created? It sounds like the best, and most trivial, solution.

Comment: Just a question: what this function will do if the backoffice provides a queri like this: `SELECT * INTO BOTemp FROM ReallyHugeTable`? Limit the mysql user to only select privilege to prevent any unwanted actions.

Comment: Actually, I know how it should be done cleanly and safely, what I ask is how to hack the current solution, **before** the deployment of this ugly thing, so I can stop it.

Comment: Partly the problem is that there may not be a current vulnerability. But having a user with privileges to change/delete data where you only want them to SELECT is just asking for future trouble. *Even if it can't be hacked now* it's still a bad thing to do. What happens when you [upgrade from mysql, because it's deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)? All of a sudden you can run stacked queries. What happens if some hacker discovers a new injection technique? Basically, if you only want a user to SELECT, why would you use anything but the standard security mechanism?

Comment: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html showing some nice examples

Comment: @MarkBaker there's not a single example that will match this case.

Comment: @Pred SELECT * INTO OUTFILE is a good start: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

Comment: How about `SELECT id AS id, password AS somefield FROM users INTO sometable ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? If there's a `id, somefield` table you've got info on, this will replace `somefield` of existing rows in that table with passwords. Also, reverting this "select into" will potentially fill **passwords** with visible data, which in turn can open access to the hacker under a detected id.

Comment: @Vesper, MySQL doesn't support `SELECT ... INTO TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any way to bypass your colleague's `checkQuery` routine. It would be trivial if you weren't using the `mysql_*` functions in PHP, but as they only allow a single statement to be executed they at least aren't vulnerable to such classics as the [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) style of attack. And in fact, this is one of the key reasons why the standard query functions in both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` *don't* allow multiple statements (this is described in the [mysqli Multiple Statements documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.html).)

I've looked at other routes and I'm pretty satisfied that your colleague's code *does* actually work. (There's a way of generating false positives, e.g. triggering the detection even on a valid SELECT query, but that's not much use to you.) And as long as you don't have functions that change data as a side-effect, it shouldn't be possible to do anything other than `SELECT` with a statement that begins `SELECT...`.

There's a possibility of writing new files to the server using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html). That's restricted to new files, so you can't clobber /etc/passwd, or whatever, but there are dangers.

The most dangerous scenario I can see would be if your MySQL server is the same machine as your PHP server, your MySQL user can write to your PHP directory, and the user you're using has FILE privilege. In that case, a carefully crafted `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` along these lines:

```
SELECT '<?php echo \'DANGER WILL ROBINSON!\';' INTO OUTFILE '/Users/matt/Sites/dangerous.php'
```

might allow someone to create a new PHP file which could be executed by then browsing to it, at which point someone can execute arbitrary PHP code. I tested this potential exploit locally and after giving a user SELECT and FILE privilege and allowing write access by MySQL to my wwwroot, I could successfully create a PHP file with the above code in it and execute it in my browser.

Apart from attacks along that particular line, which may be impossible if the user you're currently using doesn't have FILE privilege, I can't see much danger. I'm aware this doesn't help you much, but it does seem to be the answer to your question.

However, I'd still strongly advise that you use MySQL authentication and security to create a new user for this application that only has SELECT permission. This is the built-in, database-level, utterly standard, well-proven, well-tested way of solving the problem, and limits potential future problems.

For example, if someone hacks your PHP server in some other way, to the extent of being able to read your MySQL user's password, they then have access to an authenticated user with high privileges they can use for other attacks (perhaps by throwing their own scripts onto your PHP server and running them.) If the MySQL user is SELECT-only, that limits the damage that can be done to your data/database even if your PHP server is completely compromised.

Comment: @frlan MySQL [doesn't support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) `SELECT ... INTO TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I accept the answer. Our system administrator is aware of this, and no file privileges are granted, also PHP and MySQL run in differents servers anyway. BTW I will attempt to convince him one more time to do it the right way, but I'm pretty sure nothing will change... I suspect him to be secretly proud of his solution -_-'

Answer (score 10):

The correct approach to this feature (if you can't convince him it is a bad idea) is to run the queries as a limited MySQL user. Grant that user only the `SELECT` permission. You can also limit the table set if desired.

Comment: and also restrict running stored procedures / functions too?